# Do something on catching an exception

Tags: java, android

I have been developing an Application which has a specific requirement to be "extra" fault tolerant. For that, I have had like 100 places where I catch an exception and provide a different flow.

Now, I am aware of tools like Crashlytics and ACRA to send crash reports and such but business requirements do not entail going for these tools. Instead, I would like to log the stacktrace of every caught and uncaught exception to a file on the device.

You might argue that I put the code for that in catch block of every exception. Two things:

- There are considerably large number of places where the exception has bee caught and that means a lot of work
- Second, even if I were to go through all these places and put the code somehow, what about the uncaught exceptions?

So, how might I go about doing this?

Comment: why not use `AOP`. Spring provides a nice implementation of that else try this https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html

Comment: I assume that if you've caught the Exception then you know what to do. It sounds like you'd like a global handler for all uncaught exceptions, which would be: Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)